# How spy works with Jasmine in Angular 7?

Tags: jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular7

I have created this spy using spyOn

```
it("spyon ", () => {
  const searchChangeEmitSpy =  spyOn(Adders.countlist,"add");
  expect(searchChangeEmitSpy.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
});
```

and inside Adder class I have the following function

```
countlist(){ const i =0;
  this.quoteList.forEach(element => {
       console.log(element); 
       this.add(4,i++);    
  });
```

}

length of quoteList array is 2

what I am getting as a result

> Error:  : add() method does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Fabian answer, I able to debug and solve my problem. Actually, I need to trigger the function inside the class on which I was spying. after doing so, it gave me the expected output.

test case

```
it("spyOn countList add()", () => {
          const searchChangeEmitSpy =  spyOn(Adders,"add");
          Adders.addNewQuote("This is my second post");
          Adders.countlist(0);
          expect(searchChangeEmitSpy.calls.count()).toEqual(2);
        });
```

function inside the class to be spied

```
 countlist(i:number){
          this.quoteList.forEach(element => {
               console.log(element); 
               this.add(4,i++);    
          });
         //return i; 
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly spy on the function of the class `Adders` like this, instead spy on the `prototype` or create an instance of the class and spy on that. I would use two spies and implement it like this:

```
it("spyon", () => {
  const countlistSpy = spyOn(Adders.prototype, 'countlist');
  const addSpy = spyOn(Adders.prototype, 'add');

  // call your function / trigger something that calls the function

  expect(countlistSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  // more expectations here
});
```

Or with an instance of the class in the `beforeEach` block you can define your instance like this:

```
let adder: Adders = new Adders();
```

And then your test would look like this:

```
it("spyon", () => {
  const countlistSpy = spyOn(adder, 'countlist');
  const addSpy = spyOn(adder, 'add');

  // call your function / trigger something that calls the function

  expect(countlistSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  // more expectations here
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it was not what I was asking for but this helps me out in making me understand what mistake I was making and how spy actually works.